# Can I set variable column widths in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got several columns with long strings of text in a pandas data frame, but am only interested in examining one of them. Is there a way to use something along the lines of `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 60)` but for a **single column** only, rather than expanding the width of all the columns in my df?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you want to change the display in a Jupyter Notebook, you can use the [Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) feature. 
To use this formatting for only some columns simply indicate the column(s) to enlarge thanks to the `subset` parameter. This is basically HTML and CSS.

```
### Test data
df = DataFrame({'text': ['foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo', 'bar bar bar bar bar'],
                 'number': [1, 2]})

df.style.set_properties(subset=['text'], **{'width': '300px'})
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I don't see this taking any effect with pandas 0.23.0. applying this style to my df and the target column in it, the target column's size remains the same rather than being the value provided for `width`. It's probably worth emphasizing this sets a maximum width not a fixed size width.

Comment: This works for the trivial example above, but it is not working for me with a pre-existing dataframe using Pandas v1.4.2.  No error information is available showing why the setting does not change.

Comment: It does work for me except that width changes the hight of the column; yet, removing `**{'width': '300px'}` seems to maximize the length of the 'text' column (
for totally new to pandas: you have to substitute 'text' with the name of your column). –

Answer (score 66):

The easiest solution I have found on newer versions of Pandas is outlined in [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html?highlight=display%20max_colwidth) of the Pandas reference materials. Search for `display.max_colwidth` -- about 1/3rd of the way down the page describes how to use it e.g.:

`pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 400)`

Note that this will set the value for the session, or until changed.

If you only want to make temporary changes see [this info](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html) on temporarily setting context e.g.:

```py
from pandas import option_context

with option_context('display.max_colwidth', 400):
    display(df.head())
```

I've not found an obvious way to set individual columns but this approach only scales up those that need more space to the maximum you set.

Also possibly of use if trying to adjust how to fit things on screen/in tables/making space for other columns is `pd.set_option('precision', 2)` which changes the no of decimal places.

Comment: Very useful, complete, memorable, and ready-to-use answer! A nice touch with the `display` (required to pretty-print the table in a context, e.g. of a `for` loop or `with` clause).

Comment: @mirekphd Kind words! Really good point on the reason why `display` is required -- I failed to explain that bit :-)

Comment: @TomBush I have mine configured so that's not necessary. Check out [How to configure IPython to execute cell blocks the same way as a plain Python REPL does?](/q/54136057/4518341)

Comment: @TomBush where is the `display()` function imported from?

Comment: @aeroNotAuto it should be there in Jupyter already but I can't speak to its presence in iPython (edit: it's iPython.core.display) and I doubt it's regular, normal Python.

Answer (score 3):

The answer involving `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 400)` didn't work for me.

`Dataframe.sytle.set_table_styles()` worked for me. Knowing about this is great because we can do many things with it.

E.g.:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

[image]

Now, let's the change the width of Column `A` with `df.style.set_table_styles()`.

```python
df.style.set_table_styles({
    'A': [{'selector': '',
           'props': [('width', '200px')]}],
}, overwrite=False)
```

[image]

Now, let's do some more stuff:

```python
df.style.set_table_styles({
    'A': [{'selector': '',
           'props': [('color', 'red'), ('width', '200px')]}],
    'B': [{'selector': 'td',
           'props': [('color', 'blue')]}]
}, overwrite=False)
```

[image]

We can even do this kind of stuff for multi-index data frames.

```python
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[38.0, 2.0, 18.0, 22.0, 21, np.nan],[19, 439, 6, 452, 226,232]],
                  index=pd.Index(['Tumour (Positive)', 'Non-Tumour (Negative)'], name='Actual Label:'),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Decision Tree', 'Regression', 'Random'],['Tumour', 'Non-Tumour']], names=['Model:', 'Predicted:']))
df
```

[image]

Then change table properties

```python
df.style.set_table_styles({
    ('Regression', 'Tumour'): [{'selector': '',
                                'props': [('background-color', '#00aaaa')]},
                            ],
     ('Regression', 'Non-Tumour'): [{'selector': '',
                                'props': [('background-color', '#00aaff'), ('width', '200px')]},
                            ]
}, axis=0)
```

[image]

We can also play with rows.

```python
df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'tr',
                                'props': [('line-height', '40px')]},
                            ], axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

Keep in mind, replace the **payload** with your data.

```
payload = {'col1': 'col1', 'col2': 'col2'}

df = pd.DataFrame(payload)

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/xlsx')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}.xlsx"'
with pd.ExcelWriter(response) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'worksheet_name', index=False)
    # Manually adjust the width of column
    for column in df:
        column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
        writer.sheets[f'worksheet_name'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

return response
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).