# How to increase row height in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

There are good answers on how to change column width in pandas dataframes, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680147/can-i-set-variable-column-widths-in-pandas) but I couldn't find anything describing how we can change row height?

I'm trying to view two long texts side by side to compare them and I'd like to increase the row height to make it easier. Maybe some to do with `expand_frame_repr`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
styler = df.style
styler.set_table_styles([
    {"selector": "tr", "props": "line-height: 40px;"},
    {"selector": "td,th", "props": "line-height: inherit; padding: 0;"}
])
```

Change line-height for increase row height